# Error in ajax json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a bug with JQUERY AJAX, the server responds correctly with ajax, but when I try to parse it it returns an error

```
 abort: function abort()
 always: function always()
 complete: function add()
 done: function add()
 error: function add()
 fail: function add()
 getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()
 getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()
 overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()
 pipe: function then()
 progress: function add()
 promise: function promise()
 readyState: 0
 responseJSON: undefined
 setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
 state: function state()
 status: 0
 statusCode: function statusCode()
 statusText: "NetworkError: A network error occurred."
 success: function add()
 then: function then()
 __proto__: Object { … }
```

Comment: The request never made it to the server

Comment: Check the Network tab of the browser console for detailed information.